# Maximise screein Ubuntu gnome 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gnome

I have just change from Unity to Gnome in Ubuntu 16.04. I do not see anyway to maximise or minimise an app i.e Evolution  to full screen. In unity there are indicators showing full or minimised. What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

Current versions of Gnome don't show maximize or minimize buttons by default. You do have several options, including:

- Right click on the titlebar and the drop menu will provide options to maximize and minimize the window (a double-click will also maximize the window)
- Learn the keyboard shortcuts (*e.g.*, CTRL+Super+Up to maximize a window)
- Run the Gnome Tweak Tool (`gnome-tweak-tool`), go to Windows/Titlebar Buttons, and you'll see checkboxes to show both the maximize and minimize buttons

To be honest, I've been running Gnome for several years, and never even noticed that these buttons were missing...

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Rich. Spot on, I've only been on Gnome for 2 days now and still learning and do miss some of the things from Unity

Comment: Glad to help David. If the question was answered, please note it so others can reference this for future use. Otherwise, your question will appear to be unanswered from the main questions list. Thanks!